# Why is Firestore's getDocument method returning an empty dictionary?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an iOS app in Swift with user data stored in a Firebase Firestore database. The user documents in Firestore are named by the UID's of the users. To get the data from Firestore, I have the function getUserData:

```
static func getUserData(uid: String) -> [String : Any] {
        
        let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users)
        let userDocRef = userRef.document(uid)
        
        var temp: [String : Any] = [:]
        
        userDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            guard let document = document, document.exists else {
                print("document does not exist")
                return
            }
                
            let dataDesc = document.data()
            
                
            temp = dataDesc!

        }
    
        return temp
        
    }
```

I call this method in an initializer for my user class:

```
class User {
    // MARK: - Properties
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    let uid: String
    let phone: String
    var available: Bool
    var friends: [User] = []

    init?(firestoreUID: String) {
                
        self.uid = firestoreUID
        
        let data = UserService.getUserData(uid: firestoreUID)
        print(data.keys)
        
        guard let phone = data[Constants.Firestore.Keys.phone] as? String,
            let available = data[Constants.Firestore.Keys.available] as? Bool,
            let firstName = data[Constants.Firestore.Keys.firstName] as? String,
            let lastName = data[Constants.Firestore.Keys.lastName] as? String
            else {
                return nil
        }
        
        self.phone = phone
        self.available = available
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

However, when I unwrap the user instance, it gives a nil value. When I printed the keys of the retrieved dictionary from the getUserData function, the console shows only an empty array. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this so that I actually get my users' data from Firestore?

Edit: I've changed getUserData to boss's answer, but I'm not sure what should be in my User class init. I tried the call format suggested with ```
UserService.getUserData(uid: firestoreUID) { (data) in

```
        if let data = data {
            print(data.keys)
            temp = data
            
        } else {
            print("User not found")
            return
        }
        
    }
```

But I still get a "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value" when I try to query the temp dictionary.

Comment: Don't put this asynchronous method inside an object's initializer. Get the data first and then initialize the object with it.

Comment: Made the change, but still got nil being unwrapped, so I checked and realized that my code within the completion block in the getUserData call is never being executed. From what I found online, this problem is usually called by not calling completion() in the function definition, which I definitely am doing. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: The answer from @bsod is very good but it may not be the best solution for this use case, and it's using a completion handler and that doesn't seem to be what you want here. I appears you're attempting to read data from Firebase and populate a User object - the question is, what happens next? e.g. Is this part of a application authentication function where the user logs in, you read their data from Firebase and then maybe present them a task list or some other view? What's the next step that happens once the user object is populated?

Comment: The very next step is to access the properties of the user object to display a custom UILabel. I think I got bsod's answer to work for the label, but part of my application includes a friends list, and getting a full list with the async getData is proving somewhat difficult for me, albeit I am very new at this.

Comment: As mentioned that answer won't work well for this use case and you have a number of other issues in the code. For example this `return temp` will be called before the firebase data has returned from the server (most of the time). This `let data = UserService.getUserData(uid: firestoreUID)` is not how to work with a function that has a closure/completion handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:** Swift now allows functions to return asynchronously. If your app doesn't support Swift's async/await, then you must use the completion-handler model described below.*

---

`userDocRef.getDocument` is asynchronous, meaning that the call to get the document is immediately followed by the next line in your code `return temp`. It doesn't wait for the database to fetch the document so you will always return `nil`; that's how async works (versus sync).

In Swift, you cannot (or definitely should not) create a function that returns something asynchronously. Instead, the function should have an escaping completion handler that returns the async object as one of its arguments.

```
static func getUserData(for uid: String, completion: @escaping (_ data: [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
    let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users)
    let userDocRef = userRef.document(uid)

    userDocRef.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if let doc = snapshot,
           doc.exists {
            completion(doc.data())
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
getUserData(for: userId) { (data) in
    if let data = data {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```